# How to put index/ in DirectoryIndex? .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

how can i put index/ in directoryIndex?

when i access this url localhost/mywebsite/  my website is not properly arrange
but when i put localhost/mywebsite/index/ it works fine.

here is my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm index/ <-- i add this
```

thanks in advance :)

PS. localhost/mywebsite/index/ = localhost/mywebsite/index.php 
i just hide the file extension of my webpages to /(slash).

Comment: You have a typo in your question; both the working an nonworking URLs in your question are `localhost/mywebsite/`.

Comment: You could also elaborate on your actual issue a bit more detailed than "not properly arrange".

Comment: ops sorry. localhost/mywebsite/index/ what i mean is this one :D

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make any sense to give `DirectoryIndex`, which is a list of **files** that gets served in the event a **directory** is directly accessed, another directory. You probably want to just rewrite everything to that directory.

Assuming that your htaccess file is in the `/mywebsite/` directory, then add this to the top:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mywebsite/index
RewriteRule ^$ /mywebsite/index/ [L]
```

so that it looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mywebsite/index
RewriteRule ^$ /mywebsite/index/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
```

Comment: i hide the extension of my file, from .php to /(slash), localhost/mywebsite/index/ = localhost/mywebsite/index.php, normally when we access  localhost/mywebsite/ we redirect on localhost/mywebsite/index.php, right? the problem when i accesslocalhost/mywebsite/ all images are not found.

Comment: what i want to happen is when i access my localhost/mywebsite/ all images are found or it will redirect to localhost/mywebsite/index/ :)